# Enable GPS programmatically Android (without navigating to the location settings)

Tags: android, location-services

How to enable GPS programmatically, as it does happen in the official Google Maps app by just clicking on the 'turn on' option on the pop up screen (without navigating to location settings)?

Comment: Please refer this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251373/turn-on-location-services-without-navigating-to-settings-page

Answer (score 13):

The Google Maps app is using what is now available to us [as `SettingsApi`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html) the Play Services SDK. You can use `SettingsApi` to inquire as to whether your desired `LocationRequest` can be fulfilled with whatever location providers are enabled. If it cannot be fulfilled, and Play Services thinks that the user can change this, you can ask for the dialog that you see Maps display pop up.

Using `SettingsApi` is not especially simple. Here [a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Location/FusedPeriodic) for that. Using `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`, as suggested in Laurenswuyts' answer, is *much* simpler to implement.

Comment: Here is the documentation of the SettingsApi: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

Comment: What if PlayService is not available in the device? see [this unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30022133/6576302). It seems there is no solution at all!

Answer (score 5):

That's because they are using the `Settings API` in the play services as described in Commonsware's answer, which is a bit difficult. You are better off with the "old" method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE
What am i missing? i've already added the permissions.

Comment: They didn't embed the settings page into the popup. Absolutely not.

Comment: how do you get the user back to your app after redirecting them to the ugly settings screen?.. Google Maps' way is very intuitive - but I guess that's not an out-of-the-box component?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is the tradition way of approaching this problem, the creator is looking for the newest way.

Comment: You can found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744257/android-can-i-enable-the-gps-without-redirecting-the-user-to-the-settings-scree