# Android: Can I enable the GPS without redirecting the user to the settings screen like in "google maps" app

Tags: android, android-settings, android-gps

In GPS based applications, it is important that the user enable his GPS. If not then usually we would show a dialog stating that the user "*should enable his GPS from the settings to be able to use this functionality*".

When the user press OK he will be redirected to the Settings page, I don't like this solution since it takes the user out of the application context in to the settings.

I have noticed that "google maps" application has a better solution, which is to show a neat dialog when a GPS feature is needed. Upon the user's selection "OK" GPS will be enabled **directly** without any redirection to the settings.

**Can I enable the GPS  without redirecting the user to the settings screen like in "google maps" app?**

checkout the image below:

[image: Neat Dialog]

Comment: Did you mange to come right? @A.Alqadomi

Comment: @AndreHoffmann it was done already by my co-worker in our new project . the secret is to use the new API from Google , which is based on getting the location from "google play services" . the rest is straightforward

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To have that feature you need:

- First (at least) the version 7.0 of play services

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'`

- Second something like this in your code (I had it in my onCreate):

-

```
 // Check the location settings of the user and create the callback to react to the different possibilities
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder locationSettingsRequestBuilder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, locationSettingsRequestBuilder.build());
result.setResultCallback(mResultCallbackFromSettings);
```

And then create the callback:

```
// The callback for the management of the user settings regarding location
private ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> mResultCallbackFromSettings = new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
        final Status status = result.getStatus();
        //final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                // a dialog.
                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                            MapActivity.this,
                            REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // Ignore the error.
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.e(TAG, "Settings change unavailable. We have no way to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

And then, finally, in `onActivityResult` I had the following:

```
/**
 * Used to check the result of the check of the user location settings
 *
 * @param requestCode code of the request made
 * @param resultCode code of the result of that request
 * @param intent intent with further information
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(intent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && userMarker == null) {
                        startLocationUpdates();
                    }
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't confirmed the answer yet will try later .thanks for the help

Comment: Google play services is a huuge library. To only include the location api, use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'`

Comment: awesome. Thanks. saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: @AlvaroSantisteban  Could please provide a link to an official documentation for your answer ?