# Displaying Allow app to access device's location

Tags: android, permissions, location, android-gps

I am new to android programming and I need to display an alert so that user give permission to my app automatically when he/she clicks on the allow button.

Like this app

[image]

but actually my code does a message that will just take the user to the setting so he/she can change it manually, and not everyone know how to do it manually

[image]

how can I get the first alert so that the app gain permission automatically instead of my current way where it just move the user to the setting page and they have to do it manually

here is my code

```
  public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu ?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        _activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Easiest solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/40462527/1677824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing your app access to the device's location (first screenshot) is not the same as enabling GPS (second screenshot). You actually need both: first check if you have permission as other answers have suggested, then check if GPS is enabled as you are already doing.

If you want to enable the GPS programmatically, you need to use the "Settings API". Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744257/android-can-i-enable-the-gps-without-redirecting-the-user-to-the-settings-scree) on how to implement it.