# Enable Location/GPS settings without using Play Services API

Tags: android, gps, location, settings, google-play-services

As most of you might already known there is a new Location Settings Dialog API in Google Play Services.

For those who don't know here is the screenshot of Maps app which used Dialog API in action.

[image: Google Maps Location Dialog]

It is kinda unfair that google only added that API inside their play services. On the other hand, I think if they could do it,  there would be a workaround to do it. That's why I am asking this question. Any information is appreciated.

(Note: *There was an exploit which let developers to enable and disable gps/location setting programmatically. However those tricks available on SO no longer works.* Please don't post outdated answers.)

Comment: did you find any solution for that..+1 for your grt question

Comment: I think like you, it's very unfair that google only added inside their api

Comment: This works because Google apps have root access. On the other hand, Google wants you to use their own APIs because their API send location information to Google servers so your program will help Google track a person's location more accurately and more often. Welcome to capitalism :) But excellent question, I was looking for answer to the same.

Answer (score -1):

hi this works for me.

```
void initApiClient() {
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        showLocationSettingsDialog();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed() connectionResult = [" + result + "]");
                    }
                })
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    void showLocationSettingsDialog() {

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity())
                .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        getActivity(),
                                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException exception) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

for [more info](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient)