# Android :Enable location settings programatically with out leaving app or going to settings screen

Tags: android, android-location, android-settings

Maybe already answered, but is there official apis to Enable location settings programatically with out going to settings screen.

[image: This does not take to settings screen but enables location]what are best approach which works from 2.3 and above android version

Thanks

NitZ

Comment: AFASIK you cannot do that programmatically. All you can do is to send user to location by starting intent `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain have done that , but above app image does without that wonders me.Even maps app does so and how?

Comment: some android default apps have Admin permission. With that permission user can do malicious acts.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain  The one i put is 3rd party app not system app wonder how they do?

Comment: well, seems like a exploit. which app we are talking about ?

Comment: Check out "Ola cabs - Book taxi in India" - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olacabs.customer

Comment: Which device and OS you are using ? try using the same app on older version of Android, if it is still working then he should have using `reflection` and thats a exploit which have varying success rate.

Comment: Its recent GPSERvices change..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found this in google play services 7.0...fusedapiprovider/settingsapi are api to be used..
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html?m=1
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
public void locationChecker(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient, final Activity activity) {
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(
                                        activity, 1000);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

);
    }
```

Comment: this API is deprecated,  for updated code see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149434/1023441

Answer (score 0):

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

add the above line of code before the end of `locationChecker()`.