# How to turn on GPS sensor and get location from a service in Android M?

Tags: android, service, gps, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am new to a `service`. I want to turn on my **GPS sensor** and get the **lat** and **long** coordinate of GPS. I am using **Android M**, I provided the permission for my app. However, I cannot enable and get coordinate. Could you help me?

**code :**

```
//Enable gps
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(!provider.contains("gps")) {
    new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why cant you enable gps?

Comment: Why are you using a handler, a looper and a runnable to start an intent?

Comment: Because I am in BroadcastReceiver of a service. Without using Handler, I got error

Comment: You should answer all questions. Especially you should tell what your code does.

Comment: Sorry. I have deleted the runnable and it still worked. The code does not have error but the GPS sensor cannot enable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280937/android-how-to-turn-location-services-on-programmatically/37281357?s=1|0.0000#37281357

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks. It means we cannot turn on the GPS sensor from code if it is turn off. Is it right? Note that, I am using normal phone without root

Answer (score 0):

You can not **switch on** or **switch off** GPS programatically in android. Could you clearify your question more, whether you are getting trouble in switching GPS **on** and **off** or in getting lat long`
if the problem is switching it  on and off then you can guide the user to setting screen and ask them to switch on user when ever you need , here is code

```
`final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
 new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
}`
```

`

Comment: Yes. First. My GPS is turn off now. I want to use programmatically to turn on it. Then. I want to get the coordinate value from the sensor. Thanks

Comment: The one which you used is an exploit , it might not work for your device

Comment: Thanks. SO could you give me the way to get coordinate with simple way? Assume that GPS is on now

Answer (score 0):

**first you need run time permission for location in marshmallow android version**

**add your main activity**

*in oncreate() method*

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is not granted, requesting");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);

    } else {
        Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is granted");
    }
```

*below oncreate() method*

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission has been granted");

        } else {
            Log.d("PLAYGROUND", "Permission has been denied or request cancelled");
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**and then as usual your stuff**

Comment: It is not permission issue. It is turn on GS issue