# How to ask the user to enable Location (like Maps does)

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

If I open the Google Maps app with GPS switched off, and I try to get my position, I get the prompt in figure 1 (sorry if figures are in italian).

I found several answers in StackOverflow, but all of them suggest to do something like this:

```
if(gpsNotEnabled) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("GPS not enabled");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            //get gps coordinates
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
            // Do something without gps
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

But if I do this, I get a dialog like in figure 2; and if I click `enable`, I get to the GPS settings, like in picture 3, where I can switch on GPS and then get back.

[image]

This is not the behaviour we can see in Google Map: if I click `yes` in the prompt, the GPS is automatically switched on without even the need to exit the current app. How can we achieve this behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697725/enable-gps-programatically-android-without-navigating-to-the-location-settings/29697889?s=4|0.9015#29697889

Comment: Oh good, couldn't find that by myself, maybe I searched wrong. Thanks!